# Outlook Rule: Forward Meeting as iCalendar after Accepting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, rules

I'd like to forward an Outlook (2013) meeting invite as an iCalendar attachment (do not notify organizer) if I have Accepted or Tentatively accepted to that meeting. Is this possible? I have not been able to figure out the necessary rules.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add comments, so add an answer directly~

If my understanding to your issue is correct, you'd like to setup a rule to auto-forward the meeting as iCalendar after you accepted or tentatively accepted to that meeting. If so, Outlook rule would not be an option.

However, if you need rule to forward the meeting request as attachment after you received the meeting request(no matter if you will decline/accept or tentatively accept it), you can use Outlook rule with condition named "Uses the form name form", and choose meeting request as form type, then choose to forward the message as attachment. It works perfectly for me.

Comment: Yes, your understanding of my issue is correct. I currently have the same automatic forwarding rule that you subsequently described, but I want to limit the amount of meeting invites forwarded. Ideally, I only want to forward meeting invites that I accepted or tentatively accepted. What would be the best way to do this, if possible?

Comment: Then the mailbox rule(also named inbox rule) would not be an option, as it generally handles the messages when the mailbox receives them, or manually run the rule each time after the rule was created. :(

Not sure if there is any other customized/self-developed add-ins can achieve it.